# Mapping a docker volume using Portainer

Tags: docker

I'm running a Portainer docker image in an AWS EC2 linux instance.
Portainer manages containers in the local host (the EC2 instance).

I want to run a docker image and give it access to a S3 bucket,
so I have mounted the the S3 bucket as local directory in the host (EC2)
Now the issue is I'm not able to map a new docker volume to the directory that I have mounted (host).

This is how the docker-compose look like:

```
OCRmyPDF:
image: pombeirp/ocr2pdf-watchdog
container_name: OCRmyPDF
network_mode: none
volumes:
    - <path/to/archive/folder/on/host>:/archive
    - <path/to/watch/folder/on/host>:/hot-folder
    - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
environment:
  - PUID=<UID>
  - PGID=<GID>
  - "OCRMYPDF_OPTIONS=--pdf-renderer tess4 --tesseract-timeout 600 --author \"Your name\" --rotate-pages -l eng+fra+por+deu --deskew --clean --skip-text"
restart: always
```

How can I map the container folder to the host folder?

[image]

this is just a screenshot showing the options available:

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm stuck at exactly the same problem.